# AdvancedDatagrid Iterating Through Each Row of the Open Leaf/Tree

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, advanceddatagrid

I need to get the data for each row in an advanceddatagrid where the nodes are open.

For example, my ADG looks like this:

```
+ Science
- Math
  - Passed
     John Doe    |  A+  |  Section C
     Amy Rourke  |  B-  |  Section B
  - Failed
     Jane Doe    |  F   |  Section D
     Mike Cones  |  F   |  Section D
- English
  + Passed
  + Failed
- History
  + Passed
  - Failed
     Lori Pea    |   F  |  Section C
```

I tried using the following code to get the open nodes:

```
var o:Object = new Object();
o = IHierarchicalCollectionView(myADG.dataProvider).openNodes;
```

But doing the following code to inspect the object:

```
Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(o), 'object inpsection');
```

Gives me:

```
(Object)#0
  Math (2)
    children = (mx.collections::ArrayCollection)#2
      filterFunction = (null)
      length = 2
      list = (mx.collections::ArrayList)#3
        length = 2
        source = (Array)#4
          [0] (Object)#5
            children = (mx.collections::ArrayCollection)#6
              filterFunction = (null)
              length = 2
              list = (mx.collections::ArrayList)#7
                length = 2
                source = (Array)#8
                  [0] <Table>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <Grade>A+</Grade>
    <Section>Section C</Section>
</Table>
                  [1] <Table> 
    <Name>Amy Rourke</Name>
    <Grade>B-</Grade>
    <Section>Section B</Section>
....
...
..
```

Basically, I just need to create an object or array or xmllist that would give me:

```
Math    |   Passed  |   John Doe    |   A+  |   Section C
Math    |   Passed  |   Amy Rourke  |   B-  |   Section B
Math    |   Failed  |   Jane Doe    |   F   |   Section D
Math    |   Failed  |   Mike Cones  |   F   |   Section D
History |   Failed  |   Lori Pea    |   F   |   Section C
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to iterate across the openNodes object's properties and for each one grab the collection and concat the values onto a new array then use that as the source of another type of collection if necessary.  Something like this:

```
var newArray:Array = [];
for(var property:String in o)
{
    newArray = newArray.concat(o[property][0].source); //Passed, property is subject as in Math
    newArray = newArray.concat(o[property][1].source); //Failed property is subject as in Math
}
```

The only real problem with this is you're trying to also keep the Math and passed or failed in the objects, otherwise the above should work.  To get this other part working I think you need to break each of the statements above into it's own loop that iterates across the source of the openNodes object and puts the right values into a new Value Object you make up that has the subject and the pass or fail set on it.  Then you could store these values as well, also notice I'm assuming the pass fail is always organized this way in the original data structure where in each subject you'll have two arrays and the first will be pass followed by fail.